# Reputable Biometric Fingerprint Scanner & Access/Attendance Solutions?

Tags: security, fingerprint-reader

I have a client, a school, looking to implement a fingerprint or hand scanner to track both employee time and student attendance.

As per earlier conversations on here, this is not for high security & access (i.e.- automatic door locks).

From what I've researched, the field is full of unknown companies, any based in China, offering brands that don't seem to have any reputation or case studies.  It makes me very nervouse to recommend something from a market that seems quite unknown if not a tad nefarious.

Even the brand the client saw, and liked, makes me hesitate as when called, no one would quote a price and we were told a "dealer" would have to get back to us:
http://www.galaxysys.com/index.php?tpl=readers/biometric/biometric

Any personal recommendations or experiences would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
~R

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Recogniztion Systems Handpunch](http://time-masters.com/Hp-2000-Biometric-Hand-Reader_item_102.html?gclid=CP7w0ba1opwCFRIcawodtx1-jg) units.

We use Handpunch 2000 at work for our Time & Attendance duties for our janitorial staff (large airports, companies etc).  I wrote the software using the .NET api (C#). We've got about 10 units running and another 7 on the way. Very stable and no problems/failures for the past few years. I have seen these units being used in data centers for identity verification in man traps and other door locks.

The units are fairly expensive, each unit costs around 1000 bucks but it will give you the option of flexible connection (Modem, Serial, Network, etc.) as well as API in popular languages enabling you to either develop your own solution or purchase one.

Answer (score 0):

[Bioelectronix](http://www.bioelectronix.com/Biometric_timeclocks.htm) has setups that start at $199 with attendance software, sells direct, and is based in the US. Seems like they might be worth a look.

If you wanted to have a coder make something up for you, you could look at something like the [Griaule](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/index) api.

Answer (score 0):

For efficient biometric access/attendance solution, I would recommend [Aratek TruFace Series](https://www.aratek.co/product/biometric-terminal/face-recognition-truface/). [Aratek](https://www.aratek.co/) is a professional biometric brand since 2004. Their TruFace product line includes the type with body temperature sensor & RFID card for touch-less access/attendance especially during covid-19 era. It also has the type that integrated FBI FAP 20 optical fingerprint sensor for better versatility.