# Biometric scanner that scans the blood veins pattern in the palm

Tags: security, server-room, physical-security

Is there some kind of a biometric scanner that can scan the pattern of blood veins in our palm?

Related questions:

- [Reputable Biometric Fingerprint Scanner & Access/Attendance Solutions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/48321/reputable-biometric-fingerprint-scanner-access-attendance-solutions)
- [Server room door security](https://serverfault.com/questions/61257/server-room-door-security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's [being done in Japan](http://www.biometricnewsportal.com/palm_biometrics.asp) by [Fujitsu](http://www.fujitsu.com/global/news/pr/archives/month/2005/20050630-01.html).

More can be found [here](http://www.jucs.org/jucs_15_5/vascular_pattern_analysis_towards/jucs_15_05_1081_1089_bhattacharyya.pdf).

Comment: From your link, it was released 5 years ago by Fujitsu... why is it still not popular today?

Comment: If I knew that, I'd be rich.  I'm guessing cost, but having not tested it myself, it could also be complexity/benefits